# I give not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i am trying to create entity via cli. When i try to cretate getter/setter via console it gives this error: Doctrin\ORM\Mapping\MappingException

Class SfTuts\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job is not valid entity or mapped super class

Here is my code:

```
<?php

            namespace SfTuts\JobeetBundle\Entity;

            use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

            /**
             * @ORM\Entity
             * @ORM\Table(name="job")
             */
            class Job
            {
                /**
                 * @ORM\Id @Column(type="integer")
                 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
                 */
                protected $id;
            }
```

How can i solve this problem? Where is my fault? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check do you have this option in your `config.yml` file

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
```

Also your column declaration is wrong. It should be `@ORM\Column` not `@Column` becouse you are using `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` namespace for annotations, not `SfTuts\JobeetBundle\Entity`

```
        namespace SfTuts\JobeetBundle\Entity;

        use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

        /**
         * @ORM\Entity
         * @ORM\Table(name="job")
         */
        class Job
        {
            /**
             * @ORM\Id 
             * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
             * @ORM\GeneratedValue
             */
            protected $id;
        }
```

Comment: Do you use some doctrine mapping extension? Do you have doctrine orm auto_mapping: true in your `config.yml` ?

Comment: yes i solved problem. i removed doctrine folder under resource and it solved.